# Neo4j Cypher get all nodes in a circular linked list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph that looks like this

```
(user)->[:Comments]->(comment)->[:Comments]->(comment)->[:Comments]->(comment)->(user)
```

Basically it is a circular linked list of comments that a user has made. The list circles around and ends up back at the user. How do I use cypher to retrieve all of the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took a stab at this and it looks a bit convoluted to me, but here it is anyway.

Assumed the relation from the last comment to the user is :Comments

i.e instead of `..->(comment)->(user)`

I assumed `..->(comment)-[:Comments]->(user)`

```
START n=node(1) 
MATCH n-[:Comments*0..]->(c) 
WHERE c<>n 
WITH collect(c) AS allComments,n 
WITH last(allComments) AS lastcomment,n,allComments 
WHERE lastcomment-[:Comments]->n 
RETURN allComments
```

I had to put in WHERE c<>n  since the last comment->user relation is Comments. If it's something else, all the better, don't need this (it's there to just pick the last comment in the chain). Also it returns a collection.

http://console.neo4j.org/r/17d1fy

Bet @Wes Freeman has a niftier solution

Comment: Nice, how come the results in the console returns the user?

Comment: I took what you had and edited it to this: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=cx1gh9 which has the heart of yours but doesn't return the user.

Comment: Good question, let me go back to mine and check why the user comes back, didn't notice it. The console example you posted was my first attempt at it but the problem there is you will also get back chains which don't have the last comment connected to the originating user. If that's fine then you don't need all the extra stuff in mine (which is basically to establish the final link back)

Comment: Silly mistake...I had depth 0 in there, change to MATCH n-[:Comments*1..]->c and it will exclude the user

Comment: Thanks for that, I don't need the user (as I will return him anyway). +1 from me. Cheers